# Removing query string parameters with commas from GA report

Tags: google-analytics

My website is receiving referral traffic in the format:

```
/page/fbclid, undefined, nm
/page/fbclid, undefined, nm?next=/string1/string2/
```

I've tried GA's **Exclude URL Query Parameters** to no avail

[image: Exclude URL Query Parameters]

Comment: Those are unusual links. I don't think GA will be able to remove `fbclid` as a query parameter when it doesn't have a `?` before it - but I have also never seen it *without* a `?` before it, because typically Facebook adds it automatically (and hence in a standard syntax). It makes me wonder whether these are truly clicks through from Facebook. Are these pages showing up in your Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages report? Do you include GA directly or use Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Also to add to Reve's comment nm?next=/string1/string2/ the query parameter is next

Comment: "query parameter when it doesn't have a `?` before it" - these are not query string parameters. Only `name` in the 2nd URL is a "query string parameter". Do these URLs only appear in the GA report? Or do they also appear in your server access logs? Are these URLs the `Referer` URL, from which the traffic is coming? Or the target URL (ie. "referral traffic") on your site?

Comment: @Reve 1/ Those pages are showing up under Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages 2/ We use both GA & GTM.

Comment: @MrWhite They appear in the GA report. I haven't checked the server logs yet. I'm certain these are referer URLs. Our Django views.py and urls.py doesn't have URL mapped to any of the format above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up writing a script to remove `fbclid` before sending data to GA basis off this [GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overview)

```
/**
 * Checks to see if the Facebook parameter 'fbclid' is
 * found in the path, if it is, remove it.
**/
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("fbclid") > -1) {
    let pathName = document.location.pathname;

    /** Cleans path
     * From "/courses/fbclid, undefined, nm?fbclid=IwAR3CqQ-jm051SOOL7i.../"
     * to "/courses/"
    **/
    pathName = pathName.substring(0, pathName.indexOf("fbclid"));
    ga('send', 'pageview', pathName);
} else {
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```